# Best way to export data from an Excel file to SQL server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, excel, import

I have an Excel file which is already open. I want to write C# code that can export the data of that file to an SQL Server database table without giving the path of that opened file.

```
Excel.Application sourceApp;
sourceApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
sourceApp.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook sourceWorkBook = sourceApp.ActiveWorkbook;

Excel.Worksheet sourceWorkSheet = sourceWorkBook.ActiveSheet;

Excel.Range sourceRange = sourceWorkSheet.UsedRange;
```

This is the code I am using for an open Excel file.

How  to connect it to the database and an appropriate way to import it?

Comment: Like you say in your final sentece, you mean import not export, and there are too many ways to do that work, one could be read excel and then execute insert's, if the data is too much, you can use bulk insert insert instead.

Comment: @AlexKrups Actually I am implement this program for a vba application. I will use it as a library and append it to the vba code. The reason I am not doing it with VBA is- VBA lacks version control which is the main requirement of the program.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla yes I am considering the bulk insert currently but my main problem I am facing is connecting excel to the database without giving the file's path, As I want to export this data from an already opened excel sheet to database(Active one) and also import from the database to a currently opened excel sheet(Again Active one)

Comment: what did you mean when you say "lacks version control",  you can implement version control for any file, I mean you can put out your vba code and use git - github to control your changes outside excel, you obviously need vba or some wizard from excel. If the option is the second one, please let me know i will try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on many factors, however you can create a `Datatable`, map the values to a SQL table and then bulk insert the Datatable into the table. Below there's a generic snippet of this code.

```
public static void insertToDB(List<YourModel> list)
    {

        DataTable table = new DataTable("table");

        DataColumn colA = new DataColumn("Column_A", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        table.Columns.Add(colA);
        DataColumn colB = new DataColumn("Column_B", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
        table.Columns.Add(colB);
        DataColumn colC = new DataColumn("Column_C", Type.GetType("System.TimeSpan"));
        table.Columns.Add(colC);
        DataColumn colD = new DataColumn("Column_D", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        table.Columns.Add(colD);

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
            newRow["Column_A"] = item.colA == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)item.Celda_Destino;
            newRow["Column_B"] = item.colB == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)item.Celda_Origen; ;
            newRow["Column_C"] = item.colC == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)item.Celda_Destino;
            newRow["Column_D"] = item.colD;

            table.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }


        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                s.DestinationTableName = table.TableName;
                foreach (DataColumn dc in table.Columns)
                {
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.ColumnName);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Depending on your Excel files you will have to implement the logic for getting the List with "YourModel" objects